# Are the tenses well chosen?

Tags: present-tense, future-constructions

Question to a seller over the phone 1

Could you let me  know when this book **will be** in stock?

Answer

It **will be** in stock next  Monday

So I  will order it on Monday when it **is** in stock

Question to a seller over the phone 2

Could you let me know when it **is** in stock ? ( not sure if present is right here ?)

Answer

yes I will , in fact it **won't be** in stock until next Tuesday

Just would like to know if the tenses  (present or future) are ok ?
I wrote this dialogue
In fact I am not sure of the use of present in the second example. b It means for me that the first action is "check to see if it is in stock and then let me know "so present should work.

Comment: Why can't you order it now, and they ship it when it's in stock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question asks for a prediction - the bookseller expects a delivery of new stock next Monday (**not** 'on next Monday').

The second question is a request to the bookseller to let you know when (in the future) the book has arrived - the present tense expressing the future. The answer would be "Yes, I will."

"Not yet" would be an answer to the question "Could you tell me **if** it is in stock?"

Comment: OK But is my last sentence correct with future "It won't be be in stock until next Tuesday "

Comment: Yes, that's fine as a sentence.